# Derivative of transpose of a matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

If there is some function that takes the transpose of a matrix such as $g(x) = x^t$ where $x$ is some square matrix.

What would then be the derivative of the function, $\frac{dg}{dx}$?

Comment: I think I posted an answer to this same question here two or three years ago. $\qquad$

Comment: Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Identities_in_differential_form).

Comment: @AnotherTest : I don't think that answers it.  The question seems to be about the derivative of the transposition operator itself. $\qquad$

Comment: Here's a similar question that I answered: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704773/what-is-the-derivative-of-a-vector-with-respect-to-its-transpose $\qquad$

Comment: The derivative of a (continuous) linear function is the function itself. Hence $Dg(x)(h) = g(h) = h^T$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Hm, yes. Seems like I misread the question.

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\d{\delta}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\H{{\cal H}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\cas#1{\begin{cases}  #1\end{cases}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Define a fourth-order tensor $\H$ with components defined in terms of Kronecker deltas
$$\eqalign{
\H_{ijkl} &= \d_{il}\d_{jk} = \cas{
\o \qquad {\rm if}\:\LR{i=l}\:{\rm and}\:\LR{j=k} \\
0 \qquad {\rm otherwise}\\
} \\
}$$
and consider its double contraction product with an arbitrary matrix $X$
$$\eqalign{
\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^n \H_{ijkl} X_{kl}
\;=\; \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^n \d_{il} \d_{jk} X_{kl}
\;=\; X_{ji} \\
}$$
This is often written without the Sigmas using a *double-dot* product
$$\eqalign{
\H:X = X^T \\
}$$
This is one way of writing your $g$ function: $\;\;G=g(X)=\H:X$

Since $\H$ is **constant** the differential and gradient are easy to calculate
$$\eqalign{
dG &= \H:dX \qif \c{\grad GX = \H} \\
}$$
The gradient is *tensor-valued*, which is expected for a matrix-by-matrix gradient.

This result can also be written using index notation
$$\eqalign{
\grad{G_{ij}}{X_{kl}} = \H_{ijkl} \qif
\grad{X_{ji}}{X_{kl}} = \d_{jk}\d_{il} \\
}$$
An alternative to dealing with tensors is to compute a *matrix-valued* gradient with respect to a single component of $X$
$$\eqalign{
\grad G{X_{kl}} &= \H:\gradLR{X}{X_{kl}} 
 &= \H:\BR{E_{kl}} = E_{kl}^T = E_{lk} \\
}$$
where $E_{lk}$ is a matrix whose elements are all zero except for the $(l,k)$ element which equals $\o$.