# Derivative of vector and vector transpose product

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors, partial-derivative

I saw this answer here : [Vector derivative w.r.t its transpose $\frac{d(Ax)}{d(x^T)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20694/vector-derivative-w-r-t-its-transpose-fracdaxdxt).

---

[image]

---

I am finding difficult to understand the part in red. What rule is that ?

If I apply multiplication rule, shouldn't I get -

[image]

And how do one differentiate this anyways ?

[image]

Comment: he used that derivative of a linear map is the map itself. Your *product rule* is wonky.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do it componentwisely:

$$\frac{d(x^Ta)}{dx}=\left(\frac{d(x_1a_1+x_2a_2+\cdots+x_na_n)}{dx_1},  \frac{d(x_1a_1+x_2a_2+\cdots+x_na_n)}{dx_2}, \cdots, \frac{d(x_1a_1+x_2a_2+\cdots+x_na_n)}{dx_n}\right)\\
=(a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_n)=a^T$$

Comment: Aahh, din't realize it was that straightforward.. Thank you so much..

Comment: This may be obvious, but if  and  are both vectors, then  will be a scalar value, and so then wouldn't the derivative of a scalar value also be a scalar value? It feel strange that the derivative is a vector.

Comment: @TheJKFever: Remember that you are looking for the derivative with respect to $x$. Ff $x$ is a vector, it includes derivative with respect to $x_1$, $x_2$, $\dots$, $x_n$, hence a vector.