# Expansion of Matrix Function

Tags: matrices, nonlinear-optimization, matrix-calculus

Working through a non linear problem and i have no idea how he has reached the expansion from, i have wrote the question and the start of the solution which i am confused with, including the explanation given so far.

Question -

Let $A \in R^{m×n} $ with $m \geq n$ and $b \in R^n$. Prove:
Point $\bar{x} \in R^n $ is a solution of the unconstrained optimization problem
$$min\Vert Ax−b \Vert_{2}, x \in R ^n$$
if and only if $\bar{x}$ is a solution of the system of linear equations
$$A^T Ax = A^T b$$

Solution -

$$f(x) := \Vert Ax - b \Vert_2 = ( x^T A^T A x - b^Tx-x^TA^Tb +b^Tb)^{1/2} $$
$$= ( x^T A^T A x -2 b^TAx+b^Tb)^{1/2}$$

The optimization problem is equivalent to minimizing the square of $f$, as $f(x)$ is positive $ \forall x \in R^{n} $and the quadratic function is increasing on $R_{+}$.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the [normal equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Derivation_of_the_normal_equations).

First, note that $$ x^TA^Tb = (b^TAx)^T = b^TAx $$ because it is a scalar (and thus equals its tranpose).

Second, note that
$$
\frac{\partial (x^TMx)}{\partial x} = x^TM^T + x^TM
$$
which [is derived here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20694/vector-derivative-w-r-t-its-transpose-fracdaxdxt).

Then define
\begin{align}
V(x) &= ||Ax - b||_2^2 \\
&= (Ax-b)^T(Ax-b) \\
&= x^TA^TAx - x^TA^Tb - b^TAx + b^Tb \\
&= x^TA^TAx - 2 b^TAx + b^Tb 
\end{align}
We want $x^*=\min_x V(x)$, which we can look for by computing the zero of the derivative
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} 
&= \frac{\partial }{\partial x} x^TA^TAx - 2\frac{\partial }{\partial x}b^TAx \\
&= x^T(A^TA)^T + x^TA^TA - 2b^TA \\
&= x^TA^TA + x^TA^TA - 2b^TA \\
&= 2x^TA^TA - 2b^TA 
\end{align}
Thus, $ \frac{\partial V}{\partial x} = 0 $ implies
$$
x^TA^TA = b^TA \;\;\;\;\implies\;\;\;\; A^TAx = A^Tb
$$
which are the normal equations.

---

We can also derive the second identity above using components, in case that's what you wanted. If we have
$$
x^TMx = \sum_i\sum_j M_{ij}x_jx_i
$$
Then the $k$th component of the vector derivative is given by:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} x^TMx 
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \sum_i\sum_j M_{ij}x_jx_i\\
&=  \sum_i\sum_j M_{ij} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}[x_j x_i]\\
&=  \sum_i\sum_j M_{ij} [\delta_{jk}x_i + \delta_{ik}x_j]\\
&=  \sum_i\sum_j M_{ij} \delta_{jk}x_i + \sum_i\sum_j M_{ij}\delta_{ik}x_j\\
&=  \sum_i M_{ik} x_i + \sum_j M_{kj} x_j\\
&=  [x^TM]_k + [x^TM^T]_k\\
\end{align}
which implies $\frac{\partial (x^TMx)}{\partial x} = x^TM^T + x^TM$.