# Gradient of transpose of a vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

I generalize from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20694/vector-derivative-w-r-t-its-transpose-fracdaxdxt) that $\nabla_x(x^TA) = \nabla_x(A^Tx)=A^T$.

However, I'm having trouble with $\nabla_{x^T}(x^TA)$. What does it mean to take the gradient of a transpose of a vector?

Comment: The question you linked is about a derivative of that function, not the gradient. You can take the gradient of a scalar function, not of a vector $x^TA$. (I assume you are not talking of tensora here).

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the formula you wrote.

1. First, $x^{T}A \neq A^{T}x$.
2. Second, you can only take the gradient of a scalar function. This is normally defined as the column vector $\nabla f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{T}}$. In order to take "gradients" of vector fields, you'd need to introduce higher order tensors and covariant derivatives, but that's another story.
3. Maybe by $\nabla_{x}$ you meant $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$. In that case, neither $\frac{\partial x^{T}A}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial Ax^{T}}{\partial x}$ nor $\frac{\partial x^{T}A}{\partial x} = A^{T}$ hold because of (1). Nevertheless $\frac{\partial A^{T}x}{\partial x} = A^{T}$ holds for obvious reasons.

Well, I don't want to be all negativity. Here are a couple of properties of the derivatives w.r.t. a vector.

---

Say you have two column vectors $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and a scalar function $f$. Then the derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is a row vector, and the derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{T}}$ is a column vector.

For the scalar $x^{T}y = y^{T}x$ you have
$$\frac{\partial x^{T}}{\partial x}y
= \frac{\partial x^{T}y}{\partial x}
= \frac{\partial y^{T}x}{\partial x}
= y^{T}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} = y^{T}$$
$$y^{T}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x^{T}}
= \frac{\partial y^{T}x}{\partial x^{T}}
= \frac{\partial x^{T}y}{\partial x^{T}}
= \frac{\partial x^{T}}{\partial x^{T}}y = y$$

But for the derivative of a vector w.r.t. another vector there are no nice formulas except for the obvious ones.
$$\frac{\partial Ax}{\partial x} = A$$
$$\frac{\partial x^{T}A}{\partial x^{T}} = A$$

Comment: Interesting. but why is the gradient a row vector if it is the gradient of a function of a column vector variable?  Is the opposite also true?  Is there maybe a name or keyword for this, or some reference?

Comment: @Hjan it is a possible convention out of many. Unfortunately there is not a unified way to treat this, so the conventions vary from book to book. You can find out more information about the most common conventions in [the wiki about matrix calculus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions). In my answer to this question I stuck to the convention that was already being used in the question that OP linked. Hope to be of help.