# Gradient of vector matrix product

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to calculate the gradient with respect to x of the following function $$g(x) = x^TP^TPx + q^Tx + r$$ with $x,q \in R^n, P \in R^{nxn}$ and P full rank

I've been using this answer as its kind of similar https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20712/525513.  Please forgive me as I am not very experienced with vector calculus.

I create intermediate variables $P^TPx = u$ and $x^TP^TP = v$, both vectors.  Next I try to use the chain rule in a similar way as the answer linked above with $x^Tu$ and $vx$.
$$\frac{dg}{dx} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x^T} & \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x^T}{\partial x^T} \\
\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x^T} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}
$$
Now $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x^T} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^T}[x^Tu] = u$

and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[vx] = v$

and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[q^Tx] = q^T$

So I have $\frac{dg}{dx} = u + v + q^T = P^TPx + x^TP^TP + q^T$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the scalar product of a real matrix $A$ and two real column vectors $x,y$ can be transposed without affecting its value, i.e. 
$$g = y^TAx \;=\; g^T = x^TA^Ty$$
Consequently its differential can be written as
$$dg = y^TA\,dx + x^TA^Tdy$$
Setting $\,y=x,\;A=P^TP\;$ and adding the $\,q^Tx\,$ term recovers the original problem.
$$\eqalign{
dg &= x^TP^TP\,dx + x^TP^TP\,dx + q^Tdx \\
 &= \Big(2x^TP^TP+q^T\Big)\,dx \\
}$$
Therefore the gradient must be the term in parentheses $-$ or its transpose depending upon your preferred [layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions).